# Using a python module in Java through Jython but I am very new to paths and how to configure them

Tags: java, python, eclipse, module, jython

```
package dbase;
```

import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import javax.swing.JList;

import javax.swing.JTextField;

import org.jdesktop.swingx.autocomplete.AutoCompleteDecorator;

import org.jdesktop.swingx.autocomplete.ObjectToStringConverter;

public class maintrial {

public static void main(String[] args) {

JFrame mf= new JFrame("Main");

JList l = new JList(listn); //data has type Object[]

mf.setVisible(true);

JTextField tf1=new JTextField("Name");

BorderLayout bl= new BorderLayout();

mf.setLayout(bl);

AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(l, tf1,ObjectToStringConverter.DEFAULT_IMPLEMENTATION);

mf.add(tf1, bl.NORTH);

PythonInterpreter pyInterp = new PythonInterpreter();

pyInterp.exec("from mpt import p3");

}

}

This code always shows me there is no module named mpt. I am using eclipse and mpt is a python module in a python project. Please tell m how I can use a python module from this.

Answer (score 0):

If you point to the "mpt" module (assuming mpt.py) via the classpath, it should be found.

Example: Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Add External Class Folder (point to module location)

Comment: I'll tell you what I've tried: 1. appending the sys path
2. Using Properties
3.  Using the process builder. Nothing works  for me.

Comment: You may try to explicitly point to the module by path using the import internal [imp](https://www.jython.org/jython-old-sites/docs/library/imp.html)